# Date time column value is off by one hour

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time, timezone, daylight-saving-time

SharePoint showing one hour less in UI in one site collection and correct value in another site collection and both site collections/sites having same regional settings and programmatically it is showing same value in both sites in UTC.

Site1:

```
Time Zone: (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US and Canada), 
Date Value UI: 4/7/2021 3:45 AM, 
Date Value in Code (UTC): 4/7/2021 10:45 AM
```

Site2:

```
Time Zone: (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US and Canada), 
Date Value UI: 4/7/2021 2:45 AM, 
Date Value in Code (UTC): 4/7/2021 10:45 AM
```

Note:
Running CSOM code with GetItemById and checking column value

Full Time Zone Info:

```
<d:Description>(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US and Canada)</d:Description>
<d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">13</d:Id>
<d:Information m:type="SP.TimeZoneInformation">
    <d:Bias m:type="Edm.Int32">480</d:Bias>
    <d:DaylightBias m:type="Edm.Int32">-60</d:DaylightBias>
    <d:StandardBias m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:StandardBias>
</d:Information>
```